# Tensor board Visualization

Tags: tensorflow, graph-visualization, tensorboard

is there anything wrong with this code, cause this is generating an output folder with tf file inside, but when I am trying to run it on tensorboard its showing- No Graph definition file found.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sess.graph)
print(sess.run(h))
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure there is a `output` directory in the same directory where you are running that script
- make sure some files are inside `./output`
- launch tensorboard: `tensorboard —logdir=./output` from the same directory

Comment: there are files inside output, and output is in the same directory where my code is

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Firstly, do you get any error running the code because there's no indentation in the with: block.

Secondly, make sure that you are pointing Tensorboard to the correct directory in the correct location. Is anything showing up at all in Tensorboard?

Comment: Actually I didn't get any error, it prints the value, and when I open tensor board, on left side south, it shows the path that I entered but when I open graph it shows No Graph definition file found. :(

Comment: Can you go into the output folder and see what files are in there? And can you make sure you are running tensorboard from the correct directory etc.?

Comment: actually I run my directory on cmd , like - start path/of/dir,      And that actually opened the window so I guess I amm using correct directory

Comment: Yes but what's in the "output" directory?

Comment: I am creating that directory to store those graph files

Comment: Yes I know but what files are in there. Is it empty? What's there?